# equation of a resonant circuit

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need your help in something probably very trivial.
But I have no idea how to solve this issue without any knowledge about physics.

So.
$Let$ $ E(t)= \frac{U_0}{L} \cos(\omega t) $

$a= \frac{R}{L}$ , $b=\frac{1}{LC} $, $D:= \frac{1}{LC}-\frac{R^2}{4L^2} $

In the case of $R=0$

is 
$ I(t)= \frac{U_0}{L(- \omega^2+\frac{1}{LC})} cos(\omega t) + \alpha cos(\sqrt{D}t) +\beta sin(\sqrt{D} t) $

I have to proof this equation for $ E(t) $:

$E(t)= I''(t)+ a I'(t)+b I(t) $

I started to differentiate $I(t)$

but how can I differentiate $t$? I'm just confused. Thanks for any help in advance !!

Comment: What is the first and second derivative of $a \cos(b t)$, for example?

Comment: $ f'(x)= -ab sin(bt)$ & $ f''(x)= -ab^2cos(bt) $ i think?..

Comment: oh thank you...i think i see where my issue was ^^. i'll try again